# Reverse Touchpad 4-Finger Swipe

Tags: windows-10, laptop, synaptics-touchpad

I recently got a Windows 10 laptop. Opposite to my Macbook, I must swipe right-to-left to go to the right virtual desktop. Is there a way to reverse this, so I swipe left-to-right to go to the right virtual desktop?

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I have the same query and my ThinkPad laptop uses Synaptics drivers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm hoping this will be useful to those looking into the same problem. I was able to resolve OP's issue on my Windows 10 HP laptop with Synaptics drivers by doing the following:

Use regedit to navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Synaptics\SynTPEnh\ZoneConfig\Win10\4FHorizontal Scrolling`

Swap the values for `NegativeCustomZoneID` and `PositiveCustomZoneID`. That is:

Change `NegativeCustomZoneID` from Hex `88` (Decimal 136) to Hex `87` (Decimal 135)

Change `PositiveCustomZoneID` from Hex `87` (Decimal 135) to Hex `88` (Decimal 136)

Reboot, and now the four-finger swipe direction should be successfully reversed.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Comment: I see! My mistake, I'll be sure to do this from now on. Thank you!

Comment: Excellent, thanks!  I've been looking for a solution for this for months.

Comment: This worked excellently well on my Lenovo Yoga 610 with synaptics drivers. I did not even have to reboot for it to work on Windows 1903

Comment: This should be marked as the answer.

Answer (score 4):

In Windows 10, if you have a touchpad, you will probably have one of the options mentioned in the other answers:

```
Start Menu -> Settings -> Mouse & touchpad -> Reverse scrolling direction
```

Something manufacturer- or device-specific, probably accessible through Control Panel -> Mouse or something similar, as noted in other answers.

2nd Way: Powershell commands

Run this in PowerShell (from Start » All Programs » Accessories » Windows PowerShell):

```
# View registry settings
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\HID\*\*\Device` Parameters FlipFlopWheel -EA 0

# Change registry settings
# Reverse mouse wheel scroll FlipFlopWheel = 1 
# Normal mouse wheel scroll FlipFlopWheel = 0 
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\HID\*\*\Device` Parameters FlipFlopWheel -EA 0 | ForEach-Object { Set-ItemProperty $_.PSPath FlipFlopWheel 1 }
```

The command for normal (non-inverted) scrolling has the `0` and `1` swapped:

```
# Restore default scroll direction
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\HID\*\*\Device` Parameters FlipFlopWheel -EA 1 | ForEach-Object { Set-ItemProperty $_.PSPath FlipFlopWheel 0 }
```

Comment: Will this revert the direction of *all* scroll gestures or only of the 4-finger swipe? (My 2-finger scroll already works correctly, but the 4-finger swipe is inverted)

Comment: It only changes the 4-finger swipe direction. I just used this to fix the issue on my Dell Latitude laptop.